# How to control the number of subscribers for a publisher in java reactor core?

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am creating a Flux publisher to get all objects for a collection using spring mongo reactive, I don't want to create so many subscribers which can crash the system by calling finalAll objects for mongo collection. I want to control the number of subscribers(suppose I need only 10 as active at time) for a flux publisher and once the queue is free then it should be able to subscribe.

I don't know what method of reactive core I should use or I should override the subscribe() method of Publisher class.

Answer (score 0):

Your subscribers are not really the problem but the concurrent calls are. The solution would be to define a `boundedElastic` scheduler, whose thread pool is the maximum number of concurrent calls to your DB, and make sure all DB calls are executed on that scheduler.

```java
private final Scheduler dbScheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(...);

public Flux<Object> findAll() {
   return repository.findAll()
       .subscribeOn(dbScheduler)
       .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel());
}
```